# Get the last n occurences of each value of a group

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have a table named tableA having a data of

```
| col1 | col2 |
| 1    | 5    |
| 1    | 6    |
| 1    | 7    |
| 2    | 1    |
| 2    | 2    |
| 2    | 3    |
| 2    | 4    |
| 3    | 3    |
| 3    | 2    |
| 3    | 1    |
```

Then what I would like to get is the last 2 occurrences of each unique value of col1. The result would be

```
| col1 | col2 |
| 1    | 6    |
| 1    | 7    |
| 2    | 3    |
| 2    | 4    |
| 3    | 2    |
| 3    | 1    |
```

Is there a single query to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2 DESC)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    col1, col2
FROM CTE
WHERE rn <= 2
```

Comment: With this I was getting the first 2 rows? So I changed it to `rn > 2` and it worked as I like. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding on Felix's answer, assuming there's an ID column: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/04a5e/3/0

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cola ORDER BY id DESC)
    FROM ta
)
SELECT
    cola, colb
FROM CTE
WHERE rn <= 2
order by id
```

Need to reorder by ID to keep the correct order, plus ordering in the row_number() by the ID because col2 isn't always incremental.